# Why my Spark job fails with FetchFailedException: NullPointerException?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark(2.0) sql query which joins several big tables(parquet), one of the stages fails with FetchFailedException, I looked through failed tasks in stage page(in spark UI) and found that it all starts from a container failing with this stack trace:

```
6/10/13 11:44:41 ERROR server.TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 8886845294879492052
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:363)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.getFile(DiskBlockManager.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.getFile(DiskBlockManager.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.getDataFile(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.getBlockData(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getBlockData(BlockManager.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:60)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.receive(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:158)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:106)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:357)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.sort_addToSorter$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RowIteratorFromScala.advanceNext(RowIterator.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinScanner.advancedBufferedToRowWithNullFreeJoinKey(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinScanner.<init>(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:605)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As I understand as the result after this a fetch fails on other side in a task which requesting shuffle results. Any clues to why this is happening are appreciated.

Comment: You are getting the FetchFailedException because an executor has died. You need to look into why you lost the executor in the first place. The log files on the failing executor should give you an idea.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Stack trace I provided is from a failed container, is that what you asked?

Comment: That is true I have not looked in a failed executor error out, though should not it be the same?

Comment: Well, I run on YARN and YARN has it's own log files for the containers. Even if you use another resource manager I suspect there will be other log-files. Anyway, if I should venture a guess, I would put my money on a memory issue and I would also guess that the memory issue is occurring on another executor. The fetchfailed typically arises when some shuffling data is not where it's suppose to be, and in my experience that is always due to memory problems on another executor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the spark2.0 and joining serveral big tables(parquet). your problem could be quota provided for the user per application is used up in the worker nodes, so unable to write to the shuffles files (still error will be FileNotFound)

Check for the below `WARN` logs written by the `ParquetReader` in the executor logs. Also check the size of the logs created for the application and if it is huge then its eating your diskspace quota for the application.

```
parquet.CorruptStatistics: Ignoring statistics because created_by could not be parsed (see PARQUET-251)parquet-mr (build ) org.apache.parquet.VersionParser$VersionParseException: Could not parse created_by: parquet-mr (build ) using format: (.+) version ((.*) )?\(build ?(.*)\)
```

In case the above warning is written while reading each parquet record i guess which will grow based on the parquet table size.

If thats the case suppress the logging to `ERROR` or `OFF`

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console

# switch off main offenders
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler=ERROR

# Parquet related logging
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics=ERROR
#log4j.logger.parquet.CorruptStatistics=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

# setup console appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} logLevel=%p thread=%t class=%C line_number=%L %m%n

log4j.logger.org=OFF
```

The issue was fixed in the new spark version 
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/15538